# Closure - How can I find reputable manufacturers that sell (online) Windows laptops with Chinese keyboards, in Canada?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [How can I find reputable manufacturers that sell (online) Windows laptops with Chinese keyboards, in Canada?](https://superuser.com/questions/1342388/how-can-i-find-reputable-manufacturers-that-sell-online-windows-laptops-with-c)

I just thought to seek your feedback, as [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1342388/how-can-i-find-reputable-manufacturers-that-sell-online-windows-laptops-with-c#comment2009334_1342388) hints that my question may not be off-topic? Thanks!

If it is off-topic, can you please help me edit it to be on-topic? I just hope to help this senior!

Answer (score 6):

Your question would be on-topic if the only question you had was "Can I install the Chinese language pack on a laptop bought in Canada?"

It's the hardware/shopping recommendation part that sank it originally. Remove that and the question could probably stand on it's own.

Comment: Although there is no easy solution to the physical keyboard problem.  Installing a keyboard layout or language Pack is easy enough.  We can’t help locate a physical Chinese keyboard